# how do I get python to check if the number is correct

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, textbox

I am trying to make a number guesser but so far its not been working out, the code I have is

```
def c1():
     mtext = ment.get()
     mlabel2 = Label(mGui, text=mtext).pack()       
     if mlabel2 == number1:
         print ( "gj you got it" ) 
     return

number1 = random.randrange(0, 101, 2) 
mbutton = Button(mGui, text = "check", command = c1).pack() 
textbox = Entry(mGui, textvariable=ment)
```

so my question is, how do I make it print the text when you enter the right number in the textbox?

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
mlabel2 = Label(mGui, text=mtext).pack()
```

assigns `None` to `mlabel2` because `.pack()` returns `None`. Then

```
if mlabel2 == number1:
```

compares `None` with an int which can never be equal.

Did you mean to compare `mtext` with `number1` like this?

```
if int(mtext) == number1:
```

Note that `mtext` is converted to an int from a string using `int()`.

Comment: So if I want to compare 2 diffrent vallues I have to convert it?

Comment: In most cases, if you want to compare two objects of different _types_ you need to convert one to the other if such as conversion is possible (and makes sense). For example, you can't (meaningfully) compare directly a string with an integer, e.g. `"1234" == 1234` evaluates to `False`. But you can convert the string to an integer and then perform the comparison: `int("1234") == 1234` evaluates to `True`. There are some cases where you can compare different types such as integers and floats, e.g. `1 == 1.0` is `True`.

Comment: I would like to point out that `mlabel2` is always `None` due to the assignment of `mlabel2 = Label(mGui, text=mtext).pack()` involving `.pack()` as well. You need to do `mlabel2 = Label(mGui, text=mtext)` then `mlabel2.pack() `

Comment: @StevenSummers: Thanks. I have updated my answer to include that.